# How to convert numbers in hexadecimal in a file following a pattern?

Tags: bash, shell, hex

Let's say I have a file following this pattern

```
112;167;82
16;104;2
24;163;3
67;195;48
```

I want each number to be converted in hexadecimal.

```
70;A7;52
10;68;02
18;A3;03
43;C3;30
```

`printf '%x\n'` does work but only for one instance at once.

Answer (score 2):

```
while IFS=';' read -a n ; do
    printf '%02X;' "${n[@]}"
    echo
done < file | sed 's/;$//'
```

- `read -a` reads each line into an array, setting `IFS` sets the separator, i.e. the elements of the array will be the numbers on each line;
- The `printf` line prints each element of the array followed by a `;`, the trailing semicolon is removed in the `sed` command afterwards.
- `echo` adds a newline at the end of each printed array.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had to trick a little to add a 0 in front of single occurrences, but that works perfectly.

Comment: @M-Rick: Just use the `%02X` template to add leading zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

bash:

```
while IFS=';' read -ra line;  do
    line=$(printf '%x;' "${line[@]}")
    echo "${line%;}"
done < file
```

awk (probably faster for a larger file):

```
awk '
    BEGIN {FS=OFS=";"}
    {for (i=1; i<NF; i++) {
            $i = sprintf ("%x", $i)
         }
     print}' my-file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F ';' '{print toupper(sprintf("%02x;%02x;%02x",$1,$2,$3))}' file
```

Output:

```
70;A7;52
10;68;02
18;A3;03
43;C3;30
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/;/ /g;s/.*/printf "%02x" & /e;s/[a-z0-9]\{2\}/\U&;/2;s/[a-z0-9]\{2\}/\U&;/' input_file
```

In order for the `printf` command to run, `;` needs to be removed after which `printf "%02x"` can be executed.

**Output**

```
70;A7;52
10;68;02
18;A3;03
43;C3;30
```

Comment: Thank you I simplifies my tricks do add the zero in front of single occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

As nice answers with bash, awk, sed are already posted, how about a
`perl` solution (altough perl is not included in the tags):

```
perl -pe 's/\d+/sprintf("%02X", $&)/ge' file
```

- The `-pe` option tells perl to process the input line by line and
  automatically print the output.
- The `s/../../` operator performs the substitution as `sed`.
- The regex `\d+` matches a sequence of digits.
- The variable `$&` holds the matched substring.
- The `g` option to the `s` operator enables the global substitution as `sed`.
- The final `e` option evaluates the right side as a perl expression.